# getting some extra files without any extension on Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: azure-data-lake, data-lake

I am using Azure data Lake Store for files Storage. I am using operations like

- Creating a main file
- Creating part files
- Appending these part files to main file (for Concurrent append)

Example:

- There is main log file (eventually will contain logs from all
  programs)
- There are part log file that each program creates solely and then
  append to the main log file

The workflow runs really file but i have noticed some unknown file getting uploaded onto the store directory. These files name is a GUID an has no extension, moreover these unknown files are empty.

Does anyone knows what might be the reason for these extra files.

Comment: Can you please check your question and add what got lost in pasting? :)

Comment: well, i'm afraid this is the whole text. My main question is in the title that i'm getting some extra files in azure data lake storage however i'm not uploading them. @Michael Rys

Comment: What SDK/tool are you using to do the changes you mentioned? Do the appearance of these extra files correlate with ahything? (i.e., right after you do concatenate, right after you do upload, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reformatting your question. This looks like some processing artefacts that probably will disappear shortly after. How did you upload/create your files?